# How to access classes.dex of an Android Application?

Tags: android, directory, installation

When an activity is launched, the classes.dex file is loaded by the system and start executing the instructions. I need to get readonly access to the classes.dex of the same application under which the current activity is executing.

After searching for hours on the net, I could only infer that the Android Security system does not allow access to the application sandbox.

However, i need readonly access to the classes.dex file in order to accomplish my task.

Does anyone have a insight on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Were you able to achieve this? I am need of the same and not able to find any clue. It would be of great help if you can guide me through this.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on what you are trying to do, but you can access the DexFile :

```
String sourceDir = context.getApplicationInfo().sourceDir;
DexFile dexFile = new DexFile(sourceDir);
```

it gives you a http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexFile.html which you can enumerate, and load classes from.

Comment: Basically, I am trying to calculate the MD5 hash of the classes.dex for which i need access to the InputStream of the file. Thanks for the lead though!!

Comment: you probably can still look into ApplicationInfo.sourceDir. The Dex file is probably there (or in the directory if it is a directory).

Comment: quick question, though, what do you need the md5 for ?

Answer (score 4):

You may be able to obtain an InputStream for "classes.dex" in the following way:

1. Retrieve the path to the apk container of your application.
2. Retrieve the "classes.dex" entry inside your apk container thanks to JarFile class.
3. Get an Input Stream for it.

Here is a snippet of code to exemplify:

```
        // Get the path to the apk container.
        String apkPath = getApplicationInfo().sourceDir;
        JarFile containerJar = null;

        try {

            // Open the apk container as a jar..
            containerJar = new JarFile(apkPath);

            // Look for the "classes.dex" entry inside the container.
            ZipEntry ze = containerJar.getEntry("classes.dex");

            // If this entry is present in the jar container 
            if (ze != null) {

                 // Get an Input Stream for the "classes.dex" entry
                 InputStream in = containerJar.getInputStream(ze);

                 // Perform read operations on the stream like in.read();
                 // Notice that you reach this part of the code
                 // only if the InputStream was properly created;
                 // otherwise an IOException is raised
            }   

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (containerJar != null)
                try {
                    containerJar.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
```

Hope it helps!