# With Android how to get the last modified timestamp of a file in Java?

Tags: android, timestamp, .class-file

In my Android app I need to display last modified time stamp of the program, so if I have 3 class files in an app, I want to get the last modified timestamp of each, and use the latest one as the time stamp for the app, so I don't have to manually hard code it into my app, what's a good way to get that info ? The reasons I ask are :

```
[1] The java file may not be packaged with the apk file, only class files are in it. How to get time stamp of the class files ?
[2] When an apk file is copied/downloaded from one place to another, do the time stamp of the class files change ?
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to dig through the APK file.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122918/how-to-access-classes-dex-of-an-android-application).

To your second question, The timestamps would not change when copying, since the APK file is basically just a ZIP file renamed.

Answer (score 0):

Your app is a single file-  an apk file.  The individual classes inside of it aren't individual files, so they don't have timestamps.  You're going to need to find another solution.